# Plot multiple curves in the same graph in R

Tags: r

```
library(ROCR);    
lig <- unique(read.table("ligands.txt")[,1]);
dec <- unique(read.table("decoys.txt")[,1]);
uniqRes <- read.table("file1.txt",header=T);
colnames(uniqRes)[1]="LigandName";
uniqRes$IsActive <- as.numeric(uniqRes$LigandName %in% lig)
predTOTALuq <- prediction(uniqRes$TOTAL*-1, uniqRes$IsActive)
perfTOTALuq <- performance(predTOTALuq, 'tpr','fpr')
jpeg("hivpr_Rinter_ROC.jpg") 
plot(perfTOTALuq,main="hivpr - ROC Curves",col="blue")
abline(0,1,col="grey")
dev.off()
```

here is the code for plotting single curve by taking data from single file.
i want to plot 3 curves in same plot by taking data from three different files i.e. file 1, file 2, file 3
please help me to do so

Answer (score 0):

you can add `abline` or `curve` directly.

```
df1 <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 1:10)
df2 <- data.frame(x = 1:13, y = 2:14)
df3 <- data.frame(x = 6:10, y = 2:6)
lx <- range(c(df1$x, df2$x, df3$x))
ly <- range(c(df1$y, df2$y, df3$y))

plot(df1, main = "hivpr - ROC Curves", xlim = lx, ylim = ly, col = "blue")
abline(0, 1, col = "blue") 
points(df2, col = 'red3')
points(df3, col = 'yellow')
```

[image]

Comment: first two files that are ligands.txt and decoys.txt remains same
actually i want to change this command for three files
i.e.
uniqRes <- read.table("file1.txt",header=T);
uniqRes <- read.table("file2.txt",header=T);
uniqRes <- read.table("file3.txt",header=T);

Comment: just lines for ROC curve

Comment: Can above code solve your problem？if not，you `dput` some data from your `file1`, `file2`, `file3`, then i can reproduce your question.

Comment: _TITLE1 TOTAL 
ZINC08940419 -11.782
ZINC18200582 -11.738
ZINC20907200 -11.666
ZINC06752947 -11.504
CHEMBL606000.mol -11.503
ZINC05341415 -11.046
CHEMBL1651485.mol -11.012
ZINC20907206 -10.838

Comment: other two files looks same as this one